# Java Classes not referencing each other properly

Tags: java, class

I have a class A which uses objects from class B. I have them both placed in the same folder named X. I have included both classes in the same package by writing `package X;` in the beginning of each file. When I try to compile class A I get an error message saying that it cannot find the referenced symbol (object from class B). I get no error with this in Eclipse, so I assume there is nothing wrong in the code itself. How can I successfully compile my code?

EDIT:
This is class A

```
package X;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Order {
    private int orderID;
    private int orderDate;
    private int customerID;
    private String deliveryAdress;
    private List<OrderLine> orderList = new ArrayList<OrderLine>();
    double sum;

public Order(int orderID, int orderDate, int customerID, String deliveryAdress){
    this.orderID = orderID;
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
    this.customerID = customerID;
    this.deliveryAdress = deliveryAdress;
    orderList = new ArrayList<OrderLine>();
}

public int getOrderID(){
    return orderID;
}

public int getOrderDate(){
    return orderDate;
}

public int getCustomerID(){
    return customerID;
}

public String getDeliveryAdress(){
    return deliveryAdress;
}

public void addOrderLine(int articleID, int quantity, double pricePerPiece, double taxRate){
    orderList.add(new OrderLine(articleID, quantity, pricePerPiece, taxRate) );

}

public double getTotalPrice(){      
    for (OrderLine ol : orderList){
        sum = sum + (ol.pricePerPiece * ol.quantity);           
    }
    System.out.println("The total price is: " + sum);
    return sum;
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Order order = new Order(1, 20160811, 111, "Downing Street 3");
    order.addOrderLine(999, 3, 15, 3);
    order.addOrderLine(888, 1, 500, 5);
    order.getTotalPrice();
    System.out.println(order.getCustomerID());

}
```

}

This is class B

```
package X;

public class OrderLine {
int articleID;
int quantity;
double pricePerPiece;
double taxRate;

public OrderLine (int articleID, int quantity, double pricePerPiece, double taxRate){
    this.articleID = articleID;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.pricePerPiece = pricePerPiece;
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
}

public int getArticleID(){
    return articleID;
}

public int getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return pricePerPiece;
}

public double getTax(){
    return taxRate;
}

public double getTotalPrice(){
    return pricePerPiece * quantity * taxRate;
}

}
```

I try to compile it using javac "C:\Java\X\Order.java"
Class B (OrderLine) compiles without problem.

Comment: Have you tried to compile Class B first?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? And full command you're using to compile.

Comment: Yes, class B compiles just fine. Code and command added.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your case is while you are compiling your source files the package folder/directory is not getting created. 
say:
: javac B.java
-- here B.class file should be generated in x folder

when you are trying to compile
: javac A.java
-- it tries to search x.B.class

As you described its working in eclipse you can find the package in correct way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So what is the solution? The B class compiled without problem, so how come the A class cannot find it? Should I use a different command in the cmd?

Comment: Assuming your are using terminal to compile your java source files. Just copy your source files Order.java &  OrderLine.java to a new folder eg: d:\package_test then to compile open terminal goto to d:\package_test. and use javac -d . Order.java

Answer (score 0):

Try do give the **classs path** (-cp ...) of classes to use.

```
javac -cp C:\Java C:\Java\X\*.java
```

Using **eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ** and/or a build infrastructure like **maven** is advisable after having learned the commandline option.

BTW package name conventions are small letters. And you can save typing by the diamond operator `<>`.

```
List<OrderLine> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! However, when I run the javac -cp command I get "javac: no source files".

Comment: See [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). You probably have to list all files. BTW `-Xlint:all` sounds interesting.